# Controll time between ads in Unity3D Game

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

I used below obj.C code to handle time between ads to show. But now I need same code in C# for Unity3D.

```
-(void)showFullScreenads
{
    static NSTimeInterval gCBLastFail = -999;
    static bool isFirssst = true;

    if(!isFirssst)
    {
        NSTimeInterval intr = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

        float diff = intr - gCBLastFail;

        if(diff < 60.0f) // don't show ads if less than 60 sec
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            gCBLastFail = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
        }
    }

    gCBLastFail = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    isFirssst = false;

    [self showGoogleAdmobAds];
}
```

Looking for same style code for unity3d to control time between ads. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `static` in a function like you could in C++ and Object-C. Declare  the variables that uses the static qualifier outside the function. You can replace `NSTimeInterval` or `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` with `Time.time`. Better if this `showFullScreenads` function is called from the `Update` function which is invoked every frame.

The is the equivalent C# function:

```
static float gCBLastFail = -999;
static bool isFirssst = true;

void showFullScreenads()
{
    if (!isFirssst)
    {
        float intr = Time.time;

        float diff = intr - gCBLastFail;

        if (diff < 60.0f) // don't show ads if less than 60 sec
        {
            Debug.Log("Add not displayed");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            gCBLastFail = Time.time;
        }
    }

    gCBLastFail = Time.time;
    isFirssst = false;

    Debug.LogWarning("Add displayed");
    showGoogleAdmobAds();
}

void showGoogleAdmobAds()
{
    //Your admob plugin code to show ad

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lots for quick answer..I will check as soon as possible.

Comment: Sure. Let me know if there is a problem

Comment: I see you are expert Unity developer, is it possible to check from unity code that its free or paid app? here is similar question.please answer if you know code for c# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50403160/get-iphone-app-price-from-unity3d-code

Comment: I can answer that one but you've got to put some effort otherwise you are asking people to do porting work for you. Just google *"how to make http request in Unity"* then *"how to de-serialize json in Unity"*. With these two, you can put something together and if it doesn't work, create a new post with the Object-C code and the attempted C# ported code and explain the issue and I will take a look at it when I come. That post is closed because there is no effort by you to actually port the code.

Comment: I already spent more than 8hrs in doing it...not getting right call to get price...googled many time also hit code and run many time..not getting how to check whether its free or paid app...please help me if you know..ignore if it takes many hours to code.

Comment: If you've spent many hours porting the code, you should have something. Again, see my last comment. You may want to delete the other question. Create new one but show the attempt you made in the last 8 hours. Posting an Object-C code is not an attempt. Also, see what I asked you to google above if you don't have anything yet. Also make sure that the title describes the problem you have because the one you have in the other question is not good.

Comment: Ok, here is new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408020/unity3d-website-look-up-returns-nil