# Unity3D Website look up returns nil in Unity3D 4.7.2

Tags: c#, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, app-store-connect

Here is my code.

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1218822890");
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

        using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            using(Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string textRead = reader.ReadToEnd();

            Debug.Log("\nData Read = "); Debug.Log(textRead);
        }
```

I tried to read game's website link from unity code and read app price. It returns nil...what's wrong with call ?

Comment: You should use [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Your code is fine and is working correctly. It is not returning null.* You think it is returning null because the data you are receiving contains `\n\n` in it making have the json to start in on several lines below. To actually see the data, you have to scroll down a bit in the Console tab or re-size the horizontal line in the circle below.

[image]

Although, it is better to use `UnityWebRequest` in Unity but `HttpWebRequest` should also work. To answer your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50403160/3785314) question, once you download the data, use `JsonUtility.FromJson` to de-serialize it into an Object then you can access the price.

Here is what that function should look like in C#:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(CheckForPaidApp("http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1218822890")); ;
}


IEnumerator CheckForPaidApp(string uri)
{
    UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri);
    yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

    if (uwr.isHttpError || uwr.isNetworkError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error While Sending: " + uwr.error);
    }
    else
    {
        string data = uwr.downloadHandler.text;
        Debug.Log("Received: " + uwr.downloadHandler.text);

        //Serialize to Json
        RootObject jsonObj = JsonUtility.FromJson<RootObject>(data);
        List<Result> resultObj = jsonObj.results;

        //Loop over the result and show the price information
        for (int i = 0; i < resultObj.Count; i++)
        {
            double price = resultObj[i].price;
            Debug.Log("Price = \n" + price);

            if (price > 0.0f)
            {
                Debug.Log("Its Paid App\n");
            }
            else
            {
                // show ads here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Objects/classes to de-serialize json the into:

```
[Serializable]
public class Result
{
    public List<string> screenshotUrls;
    public List<string> ipadScreenshotUrls;
    public List<object> appletvScreenshotUrls;
    public string artworkUrl512;
    public string artworkUrl60;
    public string artworkUrl100;
    public string artistViewUrl;
    public List<string> supportedDevices;
    public string kind;
    public List<string> features;
    public bool isGameCenterEnabled;
    public List<object> advisories;
    public string fileSizeBytes;
    public List<string> languageCodesISO2A;
    public string trackContentRating;
    public string trackViewUrl;
    public string contentAdvisoryRating;
    public string trackCensoredName;
    public List<string> genreIds;
    public int trackId;
    public string trackName;
    public string primaryGenreName;
    public int primaryGenreId;
    public string currency;
    public string wrapperType;
    public string version;
    public int artistId;
    public string artistName;
    public List<string> genres;
    public double price;
    public string description;
    public string bundleId;
    public string sellerName;
    public bool isVppDeviceBasedLicensingEnabled;
    public DateTime releaseDate;
    public DateTime currentVersionReleaseDate;
    public string minimumOsVersion;
    public string formattedPrice;
}

[Serializable]
public class RootObject
{
    public int resultCount;
    public List<Result> results;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in Unity 4.7.2 I get error for using UnityEngine.Networking; Is this code needs Unity 5+ or anything I miss ?

Comment: `UnityWebRequest` is a 5.3 feature. Update to that version to use it or use the `WWW` API or even the `HttpWebRequest` codee from your question to receive the data. The rest of the json code should work fine unchanged. Note that 4.7 is really really old( ~4 years old now). You need to update to at least Unity 2017 if possible.

Comment: thanks a lots for your suggestions, I just used string.Contains funtion from data and done job. Thanks for great hint.

Comment: Glad I was able to help

Answer (score 1):

You should use `WWW` or the new `UnityWebRequest` classes in unity to read links from internet. 
`HttpWebRequest` will works on most platforms but will fail on some like WebPlayer or WebGL as javascript can't access IP Sockets.

Here is an example adapted from the [Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html)

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string url = "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1218822890";
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        using (WWW www = new WWW(url))
        {
            yield return www;
            string textRead = www.text;
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see this code. https://app.box.com/s/7thlfds06ox2e5mpxy71x5mrcpcn7wwb  in this 'Function Called' not printing but "Start Function Call" printed..strange..anything wrong in call ?